# How to return the status of called procedure inside procedure in teradata?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, teradata

I need to get the status of last called procedure inside procedure like 0 (or) 1, so that I can validate whether the procedure executed successfully or not.

Calling a single procedure will call multiple procedure, How to validate the status of called procedure?

In `AS400 DB2`, I used as follows:

```
call procedure_1();
GET DIAGNOSTICS V_RETVAL = RETURN_STATUS;
```

If the procedure is executed successfully, it returns 0, OR it returns 1.

Like in `Teradata`, how can I achieve?

Comment: When the procedure call fails, it was not running successfully. `GET DIAGNOSTICS` can be used in an error handler. Or you pass a variable to the SP and it's set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table table_err
(
errno number,
date_added date default Current_Timestamp(0)
);

replace procedure proc_test3()
begin
  declare l_user number;
  select 2/0 into l_user;
end;

replace procedure proc_test4()
begin
  DECLARE divide_by_zero CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '22012';
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR divide_by_zero
  BEGIN
    insert into table_err (errno) select 1;
    -- print 'ERROR: division by zero'
  END;
  call proc_test3();
end;

call proc_test4();
select * from table_err;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inner procedure you should have a out parameter which should return success when procedure completed successfully if failed it should return FAILED.

By using an exist handler you can define the exit status:-

You should use the below block in the inner procedure:-

```
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

 BEGIN
    SET lv_sql_state  = SQLSTATE;
    SET ln_sql_code   = SQLCODE;
    SET lv_out_status ='FAILED';
    ROLLBACK;
END; -- this is a good practice to always use this block in every procedure
```

So at any point your procedure fails it will result FAILED.

Now if the procedure is as below

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE database_name.proc_name1 ( OUT lv_out_status VARCHAR(10))
 BEGIN

   DECLARE lv_status                   VARCHAR(10000)  DEFAULT '';

     DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
     BEGIN
        SET lv_sql_state  = SQLSTATE;
        SET ln_sql_code   = SQLCODE;
        SET lv_out_status ='FAILED';
        ROLLBACK;
    END;


    CALL database.proc_name1(lv_status); -- variable status will capture the status of the procedure 

IF lv_status = 'FAILED' 

THEN 

    SET lv_message = 'Failure in calling of  procedure proc_name1 ';
ELSE
write other queries;

END IF;

END;
```